# Get info of how many receivers when using Messenger with Facebook SDK, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, messenger

In my application, I let the users invite other users to their group(s). During the invitation process, I store a key value together with the group_id (separate columns) to later be compared when the invited user wants to join. The invited user gets a link with the key value.

I need some restriction using this link. I want to restrict it by date AND by number of people who's used it. I also want to tell the group user how many invitations that has been sent.

Does anyone know if its possible to get information of, after a user has used Facebook Messenger from my application, how many friends the message was sent to with this function?

```
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    // In some how maybe get information from results
}
```

It dosen't of course be with this function, although this is called when a user leaves Messenger back to my application.

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: I let the user invite others to a "group" in many ways (by phone contacts, search a user directly in the app etc) in my application. I need to show to the user some information of whats been sent and I've chosen to present it by how many invites that has been sent. The best thing would be to present each invitation in more detail with name and when it was sent. I can of course just print "Invitations sent" but that is not so nice

Comment: Why do the user needs to know that they have sent notifications?

Comment: How else do the user know if the invitation process was successfull? If I were a user, I would want to see a change after the invitation is sent, just to confirm that it was successfull

Comment: Facebook tells them if the message was sent. No reason for you to tell them also

Comment: Yes, there is. Facebook doesn't tell them if the invitation process was successfull, I do that. if message sent && process successfull, everything is ok, else, problem

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope it now is more clearer. What I didn't mentioned earlier is that I need to know how many the user wanted to invite, just to make the restrictions of using the link. Check the latest edition